# Create table using php arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am using 3 php arrays to create a table, these three arrays are used to generate table headers.

```
$array1 = array('A','B');
$array2 = array('S','C');
$array3 = array('A1','B1','C1','D1');
```

Generate a table with these array values are headers.

I want to create a table like in image using these three array.

[image]

Comment: you hope have a html table or a php array 2d?

Comment: Are the arrays always this size?

Answer (score 1):

The following code is used to dynamically generate the table that you have shown. You can change the values of $array1, $array2 or $array3 respectively and table is generate dynamically.

```
<?php

$array1 = array('A','B','C');
$array2 = array('S','C','M');
$array3 = array('A1','B1','C1','D1','E1','F1');
/* Get the length of all arrays */
$lengthArray1 = count($array1);
$lengthArray2 = count($array2);
$lengthArray3 = count($array3);
?>

<table border="1" width="50%">
    <thead>
        <!-- Print the header -->
        <tr>
            <!-- For first empty space -->
            <td></td>
            <?php 
            /* Based on the length of the array display the headers */
            for($i = 0; $i < $lengthArray1; $i++){ ?>
                <!-- Align center and add the colspan wrt to $array length -->
                <td colspan="<?php echo $lengthArray2; ?>" align="center">
                    <?php echo $array1[$i]; ?>
                </td>
            <?php 
            } ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <!-- For first empty space -->
            <td></td>
            <?php 
            /* Loop through all the $array1 so that that many $array2 values will be assigned to $array1 header */
            for($i = 0; $i < $lengthArray1; $i++){ 
                for($j = 0; $j < $lengthArray2; $j++){
            ?>
                <td  align="center">
                    <?php echo $array2[$j]; ?>
                </td>
            <?php 
                }
            } ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <!-- Loop through $array3 -->
        <?php 
        for($i = 0; $i < $lengthArray3; $i++){ ?>
            <tr>
                <!-- Print $array3 value in first td  -->
                <td><?php echo $array3[$i]; ?></td>
                <?php
                /* To get the remaining td's I have multiplied $array1 X $array2 */
                for($j = 0; $j < ($lengthArray1 * $lengthArray2); $j++){
                ?>
                <td></td>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
            </tr>
        <?php 
        } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `<table border='2px solid black' bgcolor='lightgray' width="50%" style='border-collapse: collapse'>` add that to your table tag. looks better :)

Comment: @Blueblazer172 Thanks for your inputs. Ya even I had thought of the same. I left it so that no one must raise question on inline css is a bad approach. So I thought let the user handle the css the way he need. I added with = "50%" just to show how the table looks.